# Why do some quadratic graphs have a flat bottom?

Tags: quadratics

Why do some quadratic graphs have a flat bottom? This is concerning sketching the graph on a physical graph. An example of it would be the equation:y=x^2 -5x+4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "flat bottom"?

Comment: If you plot points, don't join them with straight lines? Maybe

Comment: The "flatness" is not striking for degree 2. It is more evident for higher degrees, for example with $y=x^4, y=x^6...$

Comment: @5xum What I mean by flat bottom is that when x is 2 or 3 in the equation given above, y is -2 for both the values of x.

Comment: @Paul Yes, but in our high school textbook, it is said to do so when a curve should turn smoothly.

Comment: @user324713 Sure, but $y$ is *smaller* for $x$ *between* $2$ and $3$

Comment: @5xum Yes, but the x can only be an integer in the question. Another thing, why did it reach the same point?

Comment: @user324713 For the same reason  that $x^2$ reaches the same point at $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: @user324713 The curve  only "turns smoothly" if you draw it for **all** values of $x$. If you only use integer values of $x$, then it doesn't really make any sense to talk about "smoothness", because you don't even have a curve. You just have a discrete set of points.

Comment: @5xum But I think it isn't the reason for this equation. The roots of x here, are 1 and 4.

Comment: @user324713 It is exactly the reason. Every quadratic equation takes all values (except for one) **twice**.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Mathematically, _all_ quadratic graphs $y = ax^2+bx+c$ with $a\neq0$ are parabolas. Because you're restricting to integer values of $x$ (and connecting successive dots with line segments?), you'll see a "flat bottom" if $0 < a$ and the _vertex_ of the parabola (the point on the line of vertical symmetry) lies halfway between two integers. If the vertex lies _at_ an integer, there will be a "corner" at the vertex, between two segments of equal absolute slope; at other locations of the vertex there will be a varyingly-sloped line segment "spanning the vertex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the answer you've been given in the comments (using MATLAB code)

```
x = 0:0.001:5;
plot(x,x.^2-5*x+4);
x = 0:1:5;
hold on;plot(x,x.^2-5*x+4)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are right is situating the issue of the OP in the plotting **step** (I think it is important to give the name).